# Google Analytics assign user to group

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I got a website and i want to group users behaviour based on partner
Partner will send traffic with a url param

I want to have a a group of user anaytics so i can track users behaviour based on partner

Here is an example:

a user visit my website with a partner param http://www.wesite.com/?partner=joe_doe

I will set a cookie to a user partner=joe_doe
add each to request a partner to google analytics

something  like this: 
    _gaq.push(['_asignToPartner', 'joe_doe']);

What is the best way to do something  like this and is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a user scoped custom dimensions and send in the value of the user group with your hits, or if you had user ids you could even use [user data import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user#tracking) to import even more user categories.

Below is an example where you have created the custom dimension for "Partner" and then when you receive url parameter you set that as a value in your page view.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'joe_doe'); // Where dimensions1 is your user scoped custom dimension.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: man this is amazing! It should do the work! 

the problem its i set it up but i can not see it anywhere in my reports
what google says:

Custom dimensions and metrics are available in custom reports and           available for use with advanced segments. Custom dimensions can also be used as secondary dimensions in standard reports.

but i can not see it no where

Comment: Are you using Universal Analytics (analytics.js)? custom dimensions and metrics were introduced with Universal Analytics and cannot be used with classic analytics.
You can create the custom dimensions and metrics in the Admin page, under the property column under custom definitions.
After the custom dimensions are created you should see them listed with the other dimensions in the custom reports.